# I have an array of values with a name connected to each one, I can post the values with scores.toString(); but how do I post the names along with it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

```
function calc_results(){
    var scores = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    for (var StatementCounter = 0; StatementCounter < 29; StatementCounter++){ // 29 statements it loops trough
        for (var positionCheck = 0; positionCheck < 23; positionCheck++){ // 23 parties it loops through
            if(choices[StatementCounter] == subjects[StatementCounter].parties[positionCheck].position){ // if my choice is the same as the party's choice
                var partyposition = getpartyposition(subjects[StatementCounter].parties[positionCheck].name);
                scores[partyposition]++;
            }
        }
    }
}

function getpartyposition(partyname){
    for (var positionCheck = 0; positionCheck < 23; positionCheck++){
        if(parties[positionCheck].name == partyname){
            return positionCheck;
        }
    }
}

// these are the parties that are already connected to the string, there are actually 23 of them.
var parties = [{
    name: "VVD",
  },
  {
    name: "CDA",
  },
  {
    name: "PVV",
  }
```

Here are links for if I shared insufficient code:
(some of it is dutch, but anything dutch is unimportant for the integrity of the code, thus it can be ignored)
https://github.com/ChancellorXeno/BackAtItAgain/blob/master/choice.js
https://github.com/ChancellorXeno/BackAtItAgain/blob/master/data_array.js (the opinions of parties decide their value in the scores array)

Comment: can you add some small data set and the wanted result of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scores is an array of int so just doing `score[0].toString` will work.

But parties is an array of object. You need to do something like this, `parties[0].name`. No need to to do a toString since it's already a string.

Comment: It didn't directly solve my problem, but it did lead me to the solution, so thanks!